# Timer with ajustable time delay

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers

I have a led strip, and each led should be turned on sequentially, such as this one:
[http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CTT6yvYtdos/VihhhBItwjI/AAAAAAAAAvM/q1jbUylMMdM/s400/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif][1]
The time delay between 2 consecutive leds is ts, and that time should be adjusted externally through a pushbutton switch. Each time the button is pressed, the time period shoud increment in a fixed amount.
I've already used the timerOne library, but it just works with a fixed time delay ts. How can I solve this issue with VARIABLE time delay?
I prefer to use interruptions rather than polling, since this system will be more complex (other buttons and variables will be involved).
Thanks!
Fernando

Comment: Re “the timerOne library [...] just works with a fixed time delay”: what makes you believe that?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne/blob/master/TimerOne.h#L55

Defines the function in TimerOne called `SetPeriod()`. That will change the period.

Comment: I've found the solution, through the function 
attachInterrupt(function,period);
inside loop()
In other words, I wrote 
loop(){
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(function,period);
  // rest of the code
}
where period changes inside the ISR called when the external button is pressed.
Thanks a lot @jose can u c!!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, through the function

```
attachInterrupt(function,period);
```

inside

```
loop()
```

In other words, I wrote

```
loop(){
Timer1.attachInterrupt(function,period);
// rest of the code
}
```

where "period" changes inside the ISR called when the external button is pressed.
Thanks a lot @jose can u c!!